# APC with TYPO3: high fragmentation over time

Tags: caching, typo3, apc

Using APCu with TYPO3 6.2 extensively, I always get a high fragmentation of the cache over time. I already had values of 99% with a smaller shm_size.

In case you are a TYPO3 admin, I also switched the caches `cache_pagesection`, `cache_hash`, `cache_pages` (currently for testing purposes moved to DB again), `cache_rootline`, `extbase_reflection`, `extbase_opject` as well as some other extension caches to apc backend. Mainly switching the `cache_hash` away from DB sped up menu rendering times dramatically (https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57953)

1) Does APC fragmentation matter at all or should I simply watch out that it just never runs out of memory?

2) To TYPO3 admins: do you happen to have an idea which tables cause fragmentation most and what bit in the apcu.ini configuration is relevant for usage with TYPO3?

> I already tried using `apc.stat = 0`, `apc.user_ttl = 0`, `apc.ttl = 0` (as in the T3 caching guide http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/CachingFramework/FrontendsBackends/Index.html#caching-backend-apc) and to increase the `shm_size` (currently at 512M where normally around 100M would be used). Shm_size does a good job at reducing fragmentation, but I'd rather have a smaller but full cache than a large one unused.

3) To APC(u) admins: could it be that frequently updating cache entries that change in size as well cause most of the fragmentation? Or is there any other misconfiguration that I'm unaware of?

> I know there is a lot of entries in cache (mainly JSON data from remote servers) where some of them update every 5 minutes and normally are a different size each time. If that is indeed a cause, how can I avoid it? Btw: APCU Info shows there are a lot of entries taking up only 2kB but each with a fragmented spacing of about 200 Bytes.

4) To TYPO3 and APC admins: apc has a great integration in TYPO3, but for more frequently updating and many small entries, would you advise a different cache backend than apc?

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer relevant for us, I found a different solution reverting back to MySQL cache. Though if anyone comes here via search, this is how we did it in the end:

Leave the APC cache alone and only use it for the preconfigured `extbase_object` cache. This one is less than 1MB, has only a few inserts at the beginning and yields a very high hit / miss ratio after. As stated in the install tool in the section "Configuration Presets", this is what the cache backend has been designed for.

I discovered this bug https://forge.typo3.org/issues/59587 in the process and reviewed our cache usage again. It resulted in huge cache entries only used for tag-to-ident-mappings. My conclusion is, even after trying out the fixed cache, that APCu is great for storing frequently accessed key-value mappings but yields when a lot of frequently inserted or tagged entries are around (such as `cache_hash` or `cache_pages`).

Right now, the MySQL cache tables have a better performance with extended usage of the MySQL server memory cache (but in contrast to APCu with disc backup). This was the magic setup for our my.cnf (found here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table
```

With this additional MySQL server setup, the default typo3 cache tables do their job best.